# SharePoint "List does not exist"

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list

Ok so I seem to be the only administrator managing a SharePoint website on behalf of the Health Service. However being as it's linked to the government someone made this website for free. I also assume that he made some of the webparts himself.

One of these web parts was an FAQ webpart which enabled you to created FAQs with a fancy format. Now however whenever I try to make an FAQ I can select it and it will now be ready to edit. Now however when I go to modify it, it will take me to an Error Page which says:

"List does not exist

The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user. 
Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services."

Does anyone know how to find out what the webpart is looking for. What the list is called so I can make another one to replace it? Tried looking in the ".Aspx" for the page but it doesnt keep any information on the webpart. Any ideas or pointers would be very greatful.

Thanks for looking

```
    <webParts>
     <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
        <metaData>
          <type         name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart,         Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,         PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
</metaData>
<data>
  <properties>
    <property name="FilterType3" type="string" />
    <property name="PageSize" type="int">-1</property>
    <property name="SortBy" type="string">{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}</property>
    <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
    <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="ContentTypeBeginsWithId" type="string" />
    <property name="ServerTemplate" type="string">100</property>
    <property name="Height" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterField2" type="string" />
    <property name="SystemViewFields" type="string" />
    <property name="ParameterBindings" type="string" />
    <property name="FeedTitle" type="string" />
    <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="ContentTypeName" type="string" />
    <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
    <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="DisplayColumns" type="int">1</property>
    <property name="XslLink" type="string" null="true" />
    <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
    <property name="GroupBy" type="string" />
    <property name="DataSourcesString" type="string" />
    <property name="WebUrl" type="string">/sites/cerner</property>
    <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="AdditionalGroupAndSortFields" type="string" null="true" />
    <property name="FeedDescription" type="string" />
    <property name="WebsOverride" type="string" />
    <property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">Title,Text;Answer,Note;SME,Text</property>
    <property name="DisplayName" type="string" />
    <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
    <property name="AdditionalFilterFields" type="string" null="true" />
    <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterValue3" type="string" />
    <property name="BaseType" type="string" />
    <property name="FireInitialRow" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="SortByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
    <property name="DataFields" type="string" />
    <property name="GroupStyle" type="string">DefaultHeader</property>
    <property name="DataColumnRenames" type="string" />
    <property name="HeaderXslLink" type="string">/Sites/cerner/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/FAQHeader.xsl</property>
    <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
    <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
    <property name="ViewFieldsOverride" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterField1" type="string" />
    <property name="UseCache" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="ShowUntargetedItems" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
    <property name="DataSourceID" type="string" />
    <property name="ListName" type="string">FAQ</property>
    <property name="FilterType1" type="string" />
    <property name="Default" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterType2" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterOperator1" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
    <property name="ViewFlag" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterOperator3" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
    <property name="FilterOperator2" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
    <property name="GroupByFieldType" type="string" />
    <property name="UseCopyUtil" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="Description" type="string">Use to display a dynamic view of content from your site on a web page</property>
    <property name="Filter1ChainingOperator" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterChainingOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Or</property>
    <property name="ItemLimit" type="int">15</property>
    <property name="SortByFieldType" type="string">DateTime</property>
    <property name="ListGuid" type="string">A72FB448-BAC3-4661-BEAB-F435E441AA1D</property>
    <property name="ViewContentTypeId" type="string" />
    <property name="ItemXslLink" type="string">/Sites/cerner/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/FAQItemStyle.xsl</property>
    <property name="FeedEnabled" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="MainXslLink" type="string">/Sites/cerner/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/NHSContentQueryMain.xsl</property>
    <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
    <property name="Filter2ChainingOperator" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterChainingOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Or</property>
    <property name="FilterValue1" type="string" />
    <property name="ListsOverride" type="string" />
    <property name="GroupByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
    <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
    <property name="QueryOverride" type="string" />
    <property name="UseSQLDataSourcePaging" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="Width" type="string" />
    <property name="FilterByAudience" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="FilterValue2" type="string" />
    <property name="SampleData" type="string">&lt;dsQueryResponse&gt;
                &lt;Rows&gt;
                    &lt;Row Title="Item 1" LinkUrl="http://Item1" Group="Group Header" __begincolumn="True" __begingroup="True" /&gt;
                    &lt;Row Title="Item 2" LinkUrl="http://Item2" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" /&gt;
                    &lt;Row Title="Item 3" LinkUrl="http://Item3" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" /&gt;
                &lt;/Rows&gt;
                &lt;/dsQueryResponse&gt;</property>
    <property name="Xsl" type="string">&lt;xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3/Publishing/runtime" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl cmswrt x" &gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/Header.xsl" /&gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl" /&gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ContentQueryMain.xsl" /&gt; &lt;/xsl:stylesheet&gt;</property>
    <property name="CacheXslStorage" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="Title" type="string">FAQ Content Web Part</property>
    <property name="ShowWithSampleData" type="bool">False</property>
    <property name="CacheXslTimeOut" type="int">86400</property>
    <property name="ItemStyle" type="string">NoImage</property>
    <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
    <property name="FilterField3" type="string" />
    <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string"></property>
  </properties>
</data>
```

Comment: hard to help without some precision. What's kind of web is it? Custom, XsltViewer, DataFormWebPart? What are the ULS log saying?

Comment: you should try on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he has coded the web part himself check the Application logs on the server as he may have written an error message there specifying which list it can't get to.

The other way around this is to see if the web part is working anywhere else in another site or location. If it is compare the view all site content areas and see what lists don't exist in the site that is failing compared to the site that isn't.

Another route(may take some time) is to get a tool called reflector. Drop the web parts dll in to this tool which then allows you to go through the code. This is all dependant on how experienced you are in coding etc etc

Hope this helps

Cheers
        Truez

Comment: Can I do all this through the designer? If I can I will get straight on that. However If I need access to the Server. Since its in another location I won't be able to and do not have the access. As you can tell I am not skilled in designing the sites. However I am alright at administration. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated!

Comment: Application logs I am sure you would need access to the server itself. If you have the web part working in another location on a different site you can check to see what lists exist in the working site etc. You would also need access to the server for the reflector option as well + i think reflector costs a bit of money now but it's a very useful tool for a developer. Best bet is to check the lists in the site where the web part is working IF you have this option.

Comment: I have added information about the FAQ webpart.Webpart. I don't suppose this would help find the list its looking for?

Comment: It's a CQWP by the looks of it. If you edit the page that the web part is on, select the drop down of the web part. edit this web part a window will appear at the right hand side of the screen. There should be some info in there that might help you justify which list it is.